# lateinit property action has not been initialized in kotlin, how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import android.widget.TimePicker
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import java.util.*

class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

     lateinit var action : (String) -> Unit

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return TimePickerDialog(activity, this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(activity))
    }

    override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        var min = minute.toString()
        if(min.toInt() < 10) min = "0$min"
        action("$hourOfDay:$min")
    }


    fun setListener(action: (String) -> Unit) {
        this.action = action
    }
}
```

my declare action was detected error in firebase  inside fun setlistener this.action=action how to fix it? sorry i am newbie guys, i am need more references , thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow,
Please post the exact error you experience.
I suppose its a runtime error. `lateinit var` variables must be assigned before `onCreateView` ends.

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel wrong, a lateinit variable needs to be declared and initialized _before you try to use_ it, not before onCreateView has ended.

Comment: @a_local_nobody, you’re right.
It’s more right to say that it allows you to declare non-null variables without assigning them - the most common use case (in my opinion at least) is Android components of which you do not use constructors so you can only assign variables afterwards, like `Activity.onCreate` or `Fragment.onCreateView`

Comment: Try posting the exact error you see, and format it as a code block for easier reading.

Comment: this is not a use case for lateinit. There's no guarantee in this class that someone will call `setListener` before `onTimeSet` is called. An Optional would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

The `lateinit` field holds a reference to the listener that does something with the result of the time that you've picked.

So if you show the picker dialog without setting that listener first, when the `onTimeSet(..)` function is called, which happens when you tap "OK" on the picker dialog, the `action` field still hasn't been initialised, so an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` will be thrown.

You just need to set the action listener using the `setListener(..)` function beforehand. It can even be empty as shown below.

```
val dialog = TimePickerFragment()

dialog.setListener {
    // your listener logic
}

dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "fragment-tag")
```

**Update:** In `onTimeSet`, you are passing a string to `action(..)`. In your code, `action` is a listener that does something with the string that you pass to it. But you are passing a String to the listener before it has been set to anything, that is why you are seeing an error.

`lateinit` fields must be set before they can be used.

The quickest modification to your existing class would be to apply a listener by default:

```
// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return TimePickerDialog(activity, this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(activity)).apply {
    action = { dateTimeString ->
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Time Selected -> $dateTimeString") // this outputs the String defined in onTimeSet to Logcat
    }
}
```

Then if you want to assign a different listener, you do so with `setListener()`.

Comment: i try no sir :( i am confuse , can u edit my code above? i am newbie :')

Comment: @RajivMochammadIqbalAlhadad Copy paste the second code snippet to replace the return call in `onCreateDialog`.

Comment: This would fix the OP symptom, but not address the issue, which is an incorrect usage of lateinit.

Answer (score 0):

Just before the function that uses the variable or instance, initialise it to a reasonable value or use this if its part of the class constructors